# Javascript: How do I change this to: from greater than to several predefined values

Tags: javascript

This is the code, I have:

```
    var eng, math;
    eng = prompt("enter marks");
    if(eng>80)
        if(math>80)
            document.write("admission granted");
        else
            document.write("waiting list");
    else
        document.write("admission not granted");
```

I want to change the:

```
if(eng>80)
```

and

```
if(math>80)
```

to hold several predefined values like 21, 22, 23 and so forth. So,  if I type any of the values in it gives me "admission granted"

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want, and what you're having trouble with

Comment: Thanks for the response. What I want is the if statement to have multiple values,  for example 10,11,12,13 and if I type any of them,  it should give an answer

Comment: I presume you mean multiple conditions?? if so put && to the statement which means (AND). puting || means (OR). ie --  if( eng > 80 && math>80 ) ---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to check that the value is in a list of predefined values instead of greater than or less than a value?

in that case create an array of accepted values:

```
var accepted = [22,23,25];
```

Then check that the value is contained within that array:

```
if(accepted.indexOf(eng) !== -1){
    //do stuff
}
```

This works because `Array.indexOf(value)` will return the index that the value in the array or `-1` if it doesn't exist.

***Note:*** this will not work in some browsers (mainly IE7 and IE8) [see here](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Array.prototype.indexOf) for compatibility.
In order to make sure this works in all browsers check out the polyfill example given [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: Thank you,  I  will try it in the morning.  It's 2 hours past midnight here,  so I'm going to sleep.

Comment: I tried to make it work, but I couldn't. I'm new to javascript, so I don't understand it easily. But I'll keep trying.

Comment: What was the problem?